# Pandas To Excel write to an existing xlsx file

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a dataframe to an existing Excel worksheet on one workbook. I have other worksheets in this excel workbook which should not be affected. The worksheet I am looking to overwrite is a tab called 'Data'. The code I have below:

```
    df= pd.read_sql(sql='EXEC [dbo].[spData]', con=engine)

    excel_file_path = "C:/Shared/Test.xlsx"

    book = load_workbook(excel_file_path)
    writer = ExcelWriter(excel_file_path, engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', index=False, header=[
        'A','B','C','D','E','F'])
    writer.save()
```

The code has been running for ages in debug mode with no errors but I am not sure if the above is correct in what I am expecting it to do. I can see the file says 0KB which so it has got rid of the other worksheets as the original file was 55,939kb. I was able to use ExcelWriter and engine 'openpyxl' to write to a workbook as a new sheet. But in the above code I want to replace the content of a worksheet with the data from my dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This worked added mode='a'

```
   writer = ExcelWriter(excel_file_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
```